# Describe the region $R$ representing the quarter circle with radius $2$ in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Use polar coordinates to describe the **region** $R$ representing the quarter circle in the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane

The solution to this problem is that $$R = \left\{(r, \theta): 0 \le r\le 2, \, 0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$$

I don't have the ability to post a picture, but note that I am talking about a shaded region, used for finding the area in multivariate calculus.

**Here's my question**: why does $r$ span from $0$ to $2$? In a quarter circle with radius $2$, the radius is always equal to $2$, is it not? So why exactly is the region claiming $0\le r \le2$? Here's a more concrete example:

The area of a quarter circle in the first quadrant is given by: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2r\,drd\theta.$$

Why do we integrate $r$ from $0$ to $2$? Pretty obvious that due to the definition of integration, going from $2$ to $2$ would yield a zero area, but what is the logic behind $0$ to $2$? Thanks.

Comment: $0 \leq r \leq 2$... then, why not integrating from $0$ to $2$?

Comment: @the_candyman Sorry, typo.

Comment: If it's a shaded area, then it's a filled in circle yes? like a disc? Is it talking about a region _bounded_ by a quarter circle? In which case the stuff where r < 2 describes the inside of the quarter circle of radius 2